# zxing framework is not working with 1D barcodes for iphone

Tags: iphone

i am using zxing for barcode reader into my iphone application .But it is working for QRCoder 2D barcodes .But for my app i need to scan 1D barcodes. So what should i change into my code ,
or else what should i have to do so that my app is able to scan 1D barcodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use redlaser sdk for the barcode scanning. Check this url:

http://redlaser.com/

This will be useful for the following barcodes

[image]

Comment: but the thing is we have to buy it and

Comment: No need, I think. Because I have downloaded that sdk for free. And I have used for my App

Comment: really but he has mentioned that we have to buy the Redlaser SDK.

Comment: and redlaser is private api so Is apple accept our app into appstore ,I am thinking of this . If there is no problem like that please tell me .

Comment: The redlaser.com domain is down for me at the moment - are they still in business? If not, this answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

What about the ZBar - Library ?
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html

Comment: you're welcome. I'm happy to assist as i'm a real novice iOS developer so far :D

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/zxing

It says below that the iphone port of the zxing project for android only has the QR section implemented. So zxing isnt the way to go if you are looking for 1d barcodes.

Comment: This has changed since this post.

Answer (score 0):

@Oh Danny Boy, PSB

Why don't 1D codes work on iOS devices? An initial port of the Java code to C++ for 1D codes was done some time ago but has not been actively maintained. Results generated by this code are not comparable in quality or stability to the Java code.

Because of this, it is disabled by default in the iOS classes. Contributors interested in improving and maintaining this code are welcome. It's not particularly hard; the Java code is actively maintained and not very difficult to port. The need is for someone with sufficient interest/motivation.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Comment: I don't understand from anywhere if porting the java 1d bar scanner library code to cpp for iPhone, is a lot of work.. or just few classes to convert. Can you help me ?